# I am looking for a high quality video course on elliptic curves and elliptic functions. Is there such a course available?

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, online-resources, elliptic-functions

I have been reading around the subject of Elliptic Curves/Integrals/Functions and would greatly appreciate being able to pursue my interest on an online video course.
The only video courses I have been able to find are either poor quality (production not content!) or tangential to my specific goals (e.g. a course on Riemann Surfaces I found, was taking me too far afield from my main area of interest.)
So I am asking if anyone knows of such courses could they post here any relevant information

Comment: Honestly, textbooks far outweigh video courses the more advanced you get

Answer (score 2):

Alvaro Lozano-Robledo Intro to arithmetic of elliptic curves

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYpVTXjEi1oe1OeAllJpNhFoI4B7Ws8Yl

Andrew Snowden
The purpose of this course is to prove Mazur's theorem on torsion in elliptic curves over the rational numbers. Much of the course is devoted to developing background material on elliptic curves and their moduli.

[http://www-personal.umich.edu/~asnowden/teaching/2013/679/](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Easnowden/teaching/2013/679/)